# ActiveRecord left outer join with and clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using Rails 3 with ActiveRecord and I cannot get it to generate the query I want without inserting almost plain SQL in it.

I simply want to execute this SQL query (actually the query is a little more complex but it's really this part that I cannot get right).

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.*, possible_dates.*
FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN possible_dates 
ON possible_dates.user_id = users.id 
AND possible_dates.event_id = MY_EVENT_ID;
```

which I managed to using

```
User.includes(:possible_dates)
    .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN possible_dates
            ON possible_dates.user_id = users.id
            AND possible_dates.event_id = #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(self.id)}"
    )
    .uniq
```

but I feel that I am missing something to simply add the `AND` condition of the left join using ActiveRecord query methods.
I also tried to do something like this

```
User.includes(:possible_dates)
    .where('possible_dates.event_id' => self.id)
    .uniq
```

but this yields (as expected), a query with a `WHERE` clause at the end and not the `AND` clause I want on the join.

By the way, `self` in the two snippets above is an instance of my `Event` class.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you give merge a try?  Add `.merge(PossibleDate.where('possible_dates.event_id' => self.id))`

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

I just tried and this yields exactly the same query as my last example using `.where('possible_dates.event_id' => self.id)`.

Comment: What about something like: User.includes(:possible_dates)
    .where('possible_dates.event_id = ? AND possible_dates.user_id = ?', my_event_id, self.id)
    .uniq

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here? Looking for the answer as well.

Comment: Just posted what I finally did.

Comment: Thank you for this bit `#{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(self.id)}` I had no idea.. was continually getting `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "conducting" does not exist`. Weird how you have to sanitize it. I prefer your original SQL query to the  arel_table answer, looks too complicated to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1 year later...)
After looking around, I found out that the best was probably to use arel tables.
For the above example, the following code would work.

```
ut = User.arel_table
pt = PossibleDate.arel_table
et = Event.arel_table

User.joins(
  ut.join(pt, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)
   .on(pt[:user_id].eq(u[:id])
      .and(pt[:event_id].eq(1))
   ).join_sql
).includes(:possible_dates).uniq
```

the `1` in `eq(1)` should be replaced by the correct event id.

Comment: I think your `.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN possible_dates...")` solution in the middle of your question is more readable than this solution, for most devs. But good to know what's possible with Arel tables.